# why property 'a' is not accessible from 'fn'

Tags: javascript

```
var red = {a: 2};

red.fn = function(b){
    console.log("A: "+a ", B : "+b);
}

red.fn(20);
```

this gives error:

> `a` is not defined

But i suspect `a` is already available as a global object to the function `fn` then why is it not accessible.
Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: `this.a` will be accessible. As `this` inside `fn()` will refer to `red` object when called as `red.fn(20)`. The error clearly states that `a` is not defined, `red.a` is.

Answer (score 6):

Because unlike some other languages, the `this.` qualifier is not optional in JavaScript (because it works fundamentally differently from most other languages that have `this`; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)). You need to write it explicitly:

```
red.fn = function(b){
    console.log("A: " + this.a + ", B : " + b);
// ---------------------^^^^^
}
```

(You were also missing `+` in there...)

Comment: Good catch on `+` there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
var red = {a: 2};

red.fn = function(b){
    console.log("A: "+this.a+ ", B : "+b);    //update this line
}

red.fn(20);
```

EDIT : for `a` to be accessible within `fn` as you first tried, it should have been declared as a global variable in the first place, such as `var a = 2`.
It'd still be a valid way to access it as a global object variable, but then you should have gone for `console.log("A: "+red.a+ ", B : "+b);`

Now, `this.a` implies you're using the object's properties (edited after RobG's comment), where `a` is accessible.

Comment: You should add some explanation about what you changed.

Comment: "*this.a implies you're using the object's scope*. Objects have properties, functions (i.e. execution contexts) have scope. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here the variable `a` would be translated to `window.a` which is *undefined*.

So it takes the matter up to the *scope* of the variable `a`. Like already mentioned in the answers in the post, we could use the *encapsulated* variable by using `this.a` or we could also use `red.a`.

Including few examples to explore further:

---

`window.a`:

```js
a = 5;

var red = {
  a: 2
};

red.fn = function(b) {
  console.log("A: " + a + ", B : " + b);
}

red.fn(20);
```

---

*object.a* or *red.a*:

```js
a = 5;

var red = {
  a: 2
};

red.fn = function(b) {
  console.log("A: " + red.a + ", B : " + b);
}

red.fn(20);
```

---

*How it should translate as posted with local function scope*:

```js
var red = function() {
  var a = 2;

  this.fn = function(b) {
    console.log("A: " + a + ", B : " + b);
  };
};

var redObj = new red();
redObj.fn(20);
```

Comment: This explanation cleared all my doubts. more than what i could have asked for. Big Thanks.